# jQuery autocomplete - pass selected combobox value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I need to pass selected value of "Competitor" combobox to autocomplete attached to "xref" text box. Autocomplete passes only value of firts item, even if last one is selected. How to fix it?

Controls:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Competitor", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Competitors, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("xref", null, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4" })
```

Autocomplete script:

```
    $('#xref').autocomplete({
        source: '/Products/TagSearch?Competitor=' + $('#Competitor').val()
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult TagSearch(string term, int Competitor)
    {
        string[] tags = { };
        var myList = new List<string>();
        var xrefs = db.CrossReferences.Where(p => p.CompetitorId == Competitor).Where(p => p.Reference.StartsWith(term));
        if (xrefs != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in xrefs)
            {
                 myList.Add(item.Reference.ToString());
            }
            tags = myList.ToArray();
        }
        return this.Json(tags.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)),
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It's enough to wrap it in keyup function :)

```
$("#xref").keyup(function () {
    $('#xref').autocomplete({
        source: '/Products/TagSearch?Competitor=' + $('#Competitor').val()
    });
});
```